# Add a secondary sort to an array of objects

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I have an object, `Birthday`, that has 2 properties: `name: String` and `birthDate: NSDate`. I have an array of `Birthday` objects `var birthdays = [Birthday]()` on which I'm currently using `sortInPlace` in the following manner: 
`birthdays.sortInPlace { $0.birthDate.compare($1.birthDate) == .OrderedAscending }`. This successfully sorts my array by birthDate, but I would like to add a secondary sort by name, if possible. Is this possible in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
birthdays.sortInPlace {
    let dateComparisonResult = $0.birthDate.compare($1.birthDate)
    if dateComparisonResult == .OrderedSame {
        return $0.name < $1.name
    }
    return dateComparisonResult == .OrderedAscending
}
```